# Segmentation fault when different OS

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, portability

I have a C project, and I'm quite new with C and the linux environment.

I'm working on a linux distribution with the following system info

> Linux bt 3.2.6 #1 SMP Fri Feb 17 10:34:20 EST 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux

After compiling with gcc, on the said OS, I got the waited results.

Before submitting my project to the professor, I thought of trying to compile and execute the program on another linux distribution with the following system information

> Linux feistyFawn 2.6.20-15-generic #2 SMP Sun Apr 15 07:36:31 UTC 2007
>   i686 GNU/Linux

And I get segmentation fault under this one.
To illustrate the output console. Here are the images.

Works

[image]

Fails

[image]

I'm not sure what to do now.

---

Code

A call to this function causes segmentation fault on another OS.

```
fileInEvenements(listEvents, 'A', time, queueId);
```

What it does is file in a event called A into a queue structure, listEvents.

And its definition

```
void fileInEvenements(eventStructure *listEvents, char eventType, int time_exec, int id_queue)
{
    Event *newEvent = malloc(sizeof(*newEvent));
    if (newEvent == NULL || listEvents == NULL){
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    newEvent->type = eventType;
    newEvent->execution_time = time_exec;
    newEvent->id = id_queue;
    if (listEvents->firstEvent != NULL)
    {
        // the list contains at least one event, go to the end of list 
        Event *evCurrent =  listEvents->firstEvent;
        while (evCurrent->next != NULL)
        {
            evCurrent = evCurrent->next;
        }
        evCurrent->next = newEvent;
    }
    else // the list contains no event, new event becomes first event
    {
        listEvents->firstEvent = newEvent;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please show the code that leads to this error.

Comment: Your code is (probably) wrong on both computers.  You got unlucky when it didn't crash on one of them.

Comment: Compile with debug flags and analyze with gdb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are creating a new entry in your linked list, you are attempting to append it to the list by starting at the head and iterating the list until you find a `NULL` in `evCurrent->next`. When you do find a `NULL` you stop iterating the list and, at that point, assign `newEvent` as the next entry in the list via `evCurrent->next = newEvent;` — and, of course, if there are no entries in the linked list, you make the new entry the head of the list via `listEvents->firstEvent = newEvent;`

However, at no time do you initialize the value of `newEvent->next`. Note that [`malloc()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) does not initialize the block of memory it returns. It simply allocates a block and returns it to you. See the docs here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/

The key bit is this...

> The content of the newly allocated block of memory is **not** initialized,
>   remaining with indeterminate values.

Therefore, `newEvent->next` is, for all practical purposes, a random value. Thus, your code is off into random memory walks because you are counting on it being `NULL` to terminate the linked list.

I might suggest you try [`calloc()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/calloc/) instead.

```
Evenement *newEvent = calloc( 1, sizeof(*nvEvent) );
```

Otherwise, ensure that the value of the `next` element is initialized to `NULL` when you create it.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I really agree with you.

evActuel->suivant is suppose to get the address of the next linked list, and initialising it would therefore destroys the linkage of the structure. Is it not?

Comment: @afiqjohari: you have to make sure the `suivant` member is pointing somewhere — either a valid structure or NULL.  Use [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/); it should spot the problems for you too.

Comment: @afiqjohari -- Think about it... you start with `listEvents->firstEvent` set to NULL. Then you create your first `newEvent` and you assign it to `listEvents->firstEvent` but you have not initialized `next` to NULL... it's some random value. Now you go to create a new `newEvent` and you test `listEvents->firstEvent` and find it is not `NULL` so you examine `listEvents->firstEvent->next` to see if it is `NULL` -- but it is some random value other than that... what happens? Just make the change to `calloc()` that I suggested and that problem will go away.

Comment: Yes, i just realised that!

Answer (score 1):

Add a line:

```
newEvent->next = NULL;
```

Using an unitialized field is an error.

Alternatively you can use on the following:

```
newEvent = calloc(sizeof(*newEvent), 1); // instead of malloc
```

Or

```
memset(newEvent, 0, sizeof(*newEvent)); // set all fields to 0
```